# PHP Xdebug Laravel application in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: php, laravel, intellij-idea, xdebug

Could you please advice me how properly configure Xdebug for Laravel application. I found a lot instructions for PhpStorm but they do not work for me as I'm using IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate.

What I have already achieved - I can debug single PHP script but not whole application. I cannot follow completely the instruction which is given for PhpStorm because on step when I need to configure Run/Debug Configuration I got stucked.

Much appreciation on any help in advance!

Comment: This has to do with IntelliJ configuration and nothing with actual programming. Since you have Idea Ultimate, ask Jetbrains for support.

Comment: How to run your application? Local on your machine? Virtual box, Docker? Maybe there is a mapping problem? Can you check `break at first line on php script` if InteliJ has this option

Comment: Here, with pics: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Debugging+with+PhpStorm. Little difference to IntelliJ.

Comment: Thanks, I will continue research for myself. 
Little clarification: I did not told that is related to programming. Do not know why you thought about that @jrswgtr. I do not use Virtual Box or Docker. Simple Apache installed locally on Windows machine.
Advice to look on instruction for PhpStorm is great if I did not did that before asking a question. However interface is little different and I was hoping that someone who really familiar with PHP developming in IntelliJ Idea could give advice to me.

Comment: @AleksandrPopov the point is that StackOverflow is meant for programming related problems only. For software package related problems you'll have to be on a different forum.

Comment: @jrswgtr I can see that on https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic page there is clear definition of what question are appropriate to ask here and it is quite wider than just "programming questions". My question is related to tools which programmers commonly use - both IntelliJ Idea and Xdebug. Therefore I consider this question appropriate to this forum. Thank you for understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I gathered full instruction how to work with XDebug and IntelliJ Idea Ultimate to debug Laravel application and Windows specifically (if you use other OS the installation part will be different but other should be the same):

First of all you need to install XDebug itself and configure PHP to work with it. For that:

- Find out which PHP version you use using `phpinfo()` you will need Version, Architecture and PHP Extension Build sections to complete next step.
- Go to https://xdebug.org/download.php and download appropriate build. Basically it is dll provided for specific PHP you have installed
- After that copy that DLL to Apache modules directory - for me that is `D:\OSPanel\modules\http\Apache-PHP-7-x64\modules\` as I'm using OpenServer.
- Put into `php.ini` file following configuration:

  ```
  [Xdebug]
  zend_extension="D:\OSPanel\modules\http\Apache-PHP-7-x64\modules\php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.1-vc14-x86_64.dll"
  xdebug.remote_enable = 1
  xdebug.remote_host = "localhost"
  xdebug.remote_autostart=on
  xdebug.remote_enable=on
  xdebug.remote_port=9000
  xdebug.idekey="PHPSTORM"
  ```

where `php_xdebug-2.6.0-7.1-vc14-x86_64.dll` is name of dll I personally downloaded.

- Restart Apache
- Open your Laravel project and check your Debuggin configuration (File > Settings... > Languages & Frameworks > PHP > Debug): check XDebug section if `Debug port` is the same as you specified above (it should be, if you did not changet it previously)
- Delete all your Run/Debug configurations
- Install [Xdebug Helper for Chrome](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/xdebug-helper/eadndfjplgieldjbigjakmdgkmoaaaoc?hl=ru) or any other extension if your not using Chrome ([Browser Debugging Extensions](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Browser+Debugging+Extensions))
- Hit Run > Start listening for PHP Debug Connections
- Put break point in your project and open appropriate site context
- Enjoy!

Hope that will be useful for community.